# Return React component for each D3 datum

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I've got this simple React component

```
import React from "react";
import * as D3 from "d3";

class App extends React.Component {
  app = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    let ref = null;
    const p = <p ref={node => ref = node} />
    const ps = D3.select(this.app)
      .selectAll(ref)
      .data([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]);
    ps.enter()
      .append('p')
      .text(d => "hello" + d);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" ref={node => this.app = node}>
        <p>Hello world</p>
        <p>Hello world</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to reach something like `.append(<MyComponent />)` in order to add react components dynamically.

Lets say I've got some component `<Card />` for eg, for each datum in `.select(...).data(...)` I want to append this Card component and add it to the DOM.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to do this

```
class App extends React.Component {
...
getCardComponent = (d3Node) => {
  return d3Node
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'hex')
    .attr('d', hexPath)
    .attr('fill', hexFill)
    .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
    .attr('stroke-width', 4)
    // ...etc
```

Where all attribs after the append represents the properties of the component... Any better ideas?